# HQL joined query to eager fetch a large number of relationships

Tags: java, database, performance, hibernate, jpa

My project has recently discovered that Hibernate can take multiple levels of relationship and eager fetch them in a single join HQL to produce the filled object we need.  We love this feature, figuring it would outperform a lazy fetch circumstance.

Problem is, we hit a situation where a single parent has about a dozen direct relationships, an a few subrelationships off of that, and a few of them have several dozen rows in a few instances.  The result is a pretty large cross-product that results in the hql spinning it's wheels virtually forever.  We turned logging up to 11 and saw more than 100000 iterations before we gave up and killed it.

So clearly, while this technique is great for some situations, it has limits like everything in life.  But what is the best performing alternative in hibernate for this?  We don't want to lazy-load these, because we'll get into an N+1 situation that will be even worse.

I'd ideally like to have Hibernate pre-fetch all the rows and details, but do it one relationship at a time, and then hydrate the right detail object to the right parent, but I have no idea if it does such a thing.

Suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

So we got the SQL this query generated, it turns out that I misdiagnosed the problem.  The cross product is NOT that huge.  We ran the same query in our database directly and got 500 rows returned in just over a second.

Yet we saw very clearly in the hibernate logging it making 100K iterations.  Is it possible Hibernate can get caught in a loop in your relationships or something?

Or maybe this should be asked as a new question?

Comment: Have a look at [JPA Entity Graphs](http://www.radcortez.com/jpa-entity-graphs/). With those, you can hint the JPA provider as to what you'd rather have eagerly loaded. A smart(TM) provider will then figure out a good way to reduce the number of SELECTs while not necessarily cross join over all entities. (Hibernate seems to perform better on this optimization than EclipseLink.)

Answer (score 0):

Our team uses the special strategy to work with associations. Collections are lazy, single relations are lazy too, except references with simply structure (for an example a countries reference). And we use [fluent-hibernate](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate) to load what we need in a concrete situation. It is simply because of fluent-hibernate supports nested projections. You can refer this [unit test](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-core/src/test/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/transformer/FluentHibernateResultTransformerTest.java) to see how complex object net can be partially loaded. A code snippet from the unit test

```
 List<Root> roots = H.<Root> request(Root.class).proj(Root.ROOT_NAME)
            .innerJoin("stationarFrom.stationar", "stationar")
            .proj("stationar.name", "stationarFrom.stationar.name")
            .eq(Root.ROOT_NAME, rootName).transform(Root.class).list();
```

See also

[How to transform a flat result set using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36361630/3405171)