# Hibernate nested JoinColumns results in a big query from the database with unnecessary data

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm working on some personal project but i have a question about hibernate.

I have a class structure like this :

```
@Entity
public class User {


    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fkIdCompanyUser")
    private Company company = new Company();

}
```

But inside the company i have another join.

```
@Entity
public class Company {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fkIdCompanyEstimateOption")
    private EstimateOptions estimateOptions = new EstimateOptions();

}
```

Now i do a query to get the estimate options.
But if i do it like this it loads lots of unnecessary stuff .

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/estimateoptions")
public EstimateOptions getCompanyEstimateOptions(@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal user) {

    User getuser = userDao.findByEmail(user.getName());

    EstimateOptions estimateOptions = getuser.getCompany().getEstimateOptions();

    return estimateOptions;
}
```

is there a better approach for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do such optimization. The simplest one is add bidirectional associations to `Company` and `EstimateOptions` with lazy loading. 
An example for `Company` ( I don't test. It is just a sketch.)

```
@Entity
public class Company {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fkIdCompanyEstimateOption")
    private EstimateOptions estimateOptions = new EstimateOptions();

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="company", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user; 

}
```

And do something like this (this is HQL but you can use a criteria API too)

```
from EstimateOptions options inner join options.company company inner join company.user user where user.name = :userName
```

You can see [HQL joined query to eager fetch a large number of relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33232558/3405171) for additional thoughts.

**Updated**

I am not sure but may be you can do something like this (without additional associations)

```
select options from User user inner join user.company company inner join company.estimateOptions options where user.name = :userName
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this answer but i'm kinda stuck. i keep getting a error This inspection controls whether the Persistence QL Queries are error-checked. I also made a post about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34178331/intellij-can-not-find-classloadingexception-hql-in-intellij-and-this-inspection

Comment: It was a bit of a struggle but i got it working thanks to you ;)